# show 2 images in a row and the start a new row for next image in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop

I am trying to show 2 images in a row .Curruntly when an image is displayed then the next image goes to a new row .what i want is that when 2 images are displayed in a row only  then it should go to the next row .

```
for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++)
        {
            $path = "http://verfix.com/playground_app/assets/images/upload/".$data['inspection'][$i]->image;


        $toolcopy .= '<tr style"height:350px;"> 

                <td style="width:100px;">
                    P-'.$data['inspection'][$i]->id.'
                </td>

                <td style="width:420px;">
                    <img src="'.$path.'"  width="420" height="220">
                </td>

                </tr>';

        }

        $toolcopy .= '</table>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Thank You for any help .

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, it should do the trick.

```
    $toolcopy = '<table>';
    for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++)
    {
        $path = "http://verfix.com/playground_app/assets/images/upload/".$data['inspection'][$i]->image;

            if($i === 0 || $i % 2 === 0) {
                if($i > 0) $toolcopy .= '</tr>';
                $toolcopy .= '<tr style"height:350px;">';
            }
            $toolcopy .= '
            <td style="width:100px;">
                P-'.$data['inspection'][$i]->id.'
            </td>

            <td style="width:420px;">
                <img src="'.$path.'"  width="420" height="220">
            </td>';

    }
    $toolcopy .= '</tr>';
    $toolcopy .= '</table>';[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

It places two images in two separate TD elements in the same TR, the next two images on the next row and so on.